Does this project disallow commercial use while available with dual licensing under GPL3 which allows it?
Javascript plugin
https://www.lightgalleryjs.com/license/
https://github.com/sachinchoolur/lightGallery/blob/master/LICENSE
Is dual licensed under GPL3.
If I choose to pick the GPL3 license that is available.
However, they say of their commercial license:

If you want to use lightGallery to develop commercial sites, themes, projects,
and applications, the Commercial license is the appropriate license. With this
option, your source code is kept proprietary.

The use of "appropriate license" sounds to me like their GPL3 license grant is somehow inappropriate for (or maybe excluded from) commercial purposes. Are they able to to restrict me using it in an opensource project that is used for commercial purposes like an e-shop?
I don't get it, I understand that I should make my code gpl3 as well if I chose gpl3, but I do not understand how they offer a license that allows commercial use, but also claim they don't.

Dual-licensing and multi-licensing are best understood by imagining software as physical copies like CDs. If the software project is dual-licensed under BSD-2 and GPLv3, it means the copyright holders provide two boxes of CDs in different packages, one box has CDs with a GPLv3 license printed on its cover, another box has CDs with a BSD-2 license printed on the cover, but the code is otherwise identical. As a user, you only need to follow the license on the CD you have chosen (developers are copyright holders, so they must agree to release the work under all licenses, but users only pick one).

The GPL does not say anything about commercial use. The GPL requires you to share your derivative works.

IIRC, there was a rule here on stackexchange.com, that a mere hyperlink is not enough for citation. As the answers showed, your question is a very good example, why such a rule is good thing.

They're not.  What they say on the linked page is "if you are using the library for business, commercial sites, projects, and applications, choose the commercial license to keep your source proprietary, to yourself".  They don't say that if you're using the library for commercial purposes that you must choose the commercial licence option; they say only that if you're so using it, you may choose the commercial licence option.
If you take the library under GPLv3, and you use it to make an application that you sell to clients, you will need to give your clients full GPLv3 access to the source, and the usual rights that go along with free software.  This makes for a tricky business model - you may well only ever sell one copy - so if that's your business plan, then you might well want to get the commercial licence option instead.
If all you're doing with their library is making a larger application to run online on your server(s), then GPLv3 is probably fine for you.  Were you to distribute any copies of your application, you would need to do so under GPLv3; but if you don't distribute it, you don't have that problem.
That being said, it has been pointed out below (thanks, Philip!) that this particular library is JavaScript-heavy.  JavaScript being code that is downloaded to the end-user's browser, for execution therein, that has distribution implications for your app.  We discuss those in greater length in this question.

Another confusion about 'commercial' and 'closed source'. The way I understand the question is that the OP is ready to put his/her code under GPL, while using it for commercial purposes (running an e-shop). Cash Flow for the OP comes from selling stuff, not from selling SW.


How are they able to to restrict me using it in an opensource project that is used for commercial purposes (e-shop)?

How did you come to such an idea? Here is what the link you yourself cited says exactly:

Commercial license
If you want to use lightGallery to develop commercial sites, themes,
projects, and applications, the Commercial license is the appropriate
license. With this option, your source code is kept proprietary. Read
more about the commercial
license
Open source license
If you are creating an open source application under a license
compatible with the GNU GPL license v3, you may use this project under
the terms of the GPLv3.

Even if we treat this as something legally binding (rather than just an advertisement, which it really is), I fail to see any additional restriction on commercial use here.

"I would like to downvote you" at the start is better expressed as a comment in the question so that the question can be improved. I'm not quite sure what your complaint is exactly, but perhaps it's because the OP is just posting a link without much introductory context? In any case, such an inadequacy would be easily adressed in the question itself.

@Brandin, and if it is addressed, the question is no more, as it is based on misquotation: ‘How can they say they disallow commercial use...’ — they simply do not. That was my point.

So, if I understand, the question is based on a misconception or a misquotation. Might it be better just to say that directly in your answer, then, in a more matter-of-fact way, e.g. "(I feel that) your question is based on a misconception (or a misunderstanding, or a misquotation, a misreading, etc.)." That would be better received than "I would like to downvote this" which is going to be poorly received by the OP and just confusing for others who want to know what you're trying to say. It's also a bit contrary to what downvotes are supposed to be about, anyway.
